# LC CIRCUIT ISSUE

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, passive-networks

I am high school boy doing his homework on the circuit, I came across this question , [image]

I need to find maximum current that will flow in the circuit 
 What I have tried :) It's a weird one because when i connect the two capacitors in series the total charge on the connected plates isn't zero . I do not not how to approach  this. I tried energy conservation too but cannot go through it completely. 
 Edit :)  first answer said that, I can assume a single capacitor in place of two, taking voltage across them 5v0 can I solve it by LC oscillation now.

Comment: Draw a circuit and please be clearer about what it is that you don't understand. If you are trying to use LaTex then put an "\" in front of the "$"

Comment: Not interested in similar circuits. Don't be lazy, post a picture or draw the circuit using the tools in the question editor. Fix the "$" stuff too. What does "Cv_0" actually convey here? It means nothing useful to me.

Comment: Sorry sir give me a minute I will update it. @andy aka

Comment: Are the capacitors pre-charged then applied to the inductor via some form of switch? Is that what this question is about? You've said what you've tried but then gone on to to make an observation about capacitors in series that doesn't ring true. If you've tried to solve this then show your working. Using energy conservation will work in this example.

Comment: Yes sir capacitor first charges and then connected @andy aka

Comment: Problem is that neither I know the final charge nor potential.

Comment: There is no final charge because the circuit will oscillate indefinitely.

Comment: If there is a single capacitor and Inductor I can solve it by LC oscillation, but here they are two, who already charge to different potential.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99906/discussion-between-yuvraj-singh-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score 1):

The total initial voltage is 5Vo so the inductor will see an sine voltage = +/-5V0.

The total Capacitance in series is reduced 1/C= 1/C1 + 1/C2.

--||-||— = 2/3C total capacitance.

- another example two identical capacitors in series result in new Ctot = 1/2 C but series string voltage adds up

1V + 4V = 5Vdc  initial condition across inductor L with 0 initial current at t=0.

The running sine peak voltage across each cap will be due to the ratio of each C values in series to the string

C value = 1/(1+2) +2/(1+2) = 1/3+2/3.

Hint: The  smaller cap will see the bigger voltage so what are they? With Voltage ratio being 1/3+2/3 of V(L) inductor across 1C + 2C.

5Vdc results in 10V peak-peak sine wave. +/-5V across L.

Since the voltage ratio depends on the ratio of each C to the total inverse to its value as the smaller cap charges up faster.

Thus 1C will will swing from

[Simulation Answer](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2015.472767971186109%2050%205%2043%0Aw%20272%2080%20288%2080%202%0Ac%20272%2080%20272%20192%200%200.000009999999999999999%20-3.3389752981341214%0Al%20560%2096%20560%20304%200%201%20-0.014091257595206965%0Av%20144%20192%20144%20128%200%200%2040%201%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%2080%20272%2080%200%200.01%0Aw%20144%20192%20272%20192%200%0Aw%20272%20304%20368%20304%200%0Ar%20176%20304%20272%20304%200%200.01%0Av%20144%20288%20144%20192%200%200%2040%204%200%200%200.5%0Ac%20272%20192%20272%20304%200%200.000039999999999999996%202.915256175448288%0AS%20288%2080%20352%2080%200%201%20true%201%202%0AS%20144%2096%20176%2096%200%201%20false%201%202%0AS%20144%20320%20176%20320%200%201%20false%201%202%0Aw%20144%20128%20176%20128%200%0Aw%20144%20192%20176%20192%200%0Aw%20144%20288%20144%20320%200%0Aw%20144%20288%20176%20288%200%0Ap%20176%20192%20176%20288%201%200%0Ap%20176%20128%20176%20192%201%200%0Aw%20144%20128%20144%2096%200%0Ag%20272%20304%20272%20320%200%0Aw%20272%20192%20288%20192%202%0A403%20304%20112%20432%20176%200%201_64_0_4354_10_0.00009765625_0_2_1_3%0A403%20304%20224%20432%20288%200%209_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_9_3%0A403%20432%20176%20544%20240%200%202_64_0_4362_5_0.1_0_2_2_3%0Ax%20301%2040%20430%2043%204%2012%20click%5Csany%5Csganged%5Csswitch%0Aw%20560%2096%20352%2096%200%0Aw%20368%20304%20560%20304%200%0A38%201%200%200.000001%200.000101%20Capacitance%0A38%202%200%200.01%201.01%20Inductance%0A) : No peeking.
[Simulation another example with same voltages](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+15.472767971186109+50+5+43%0Aw+272+80+288+80+2%0Ac+272+80+272+192+0+0.000009999999999999999+-4.117017877260973%0Al+560+96+560+304+0+1+-0.010906123859499996%0Av+144+192+144+128+0+0+40+1+0+0+0.5%0Ar+176+80+272+80+0+0.01%0Aw+144+192+272+192+0%0Aw+272+304+368+304+0%0Ar+176+304+272+304+0+0.01%0Av+144+288+144+192+0+0+40+4+0+0+0.5%0Ac+272+192+272+304+0+0.000019999999999999998+1.4414912102827098%0AS+288+80+352+80+0+1+true+1+2%0AS+144+96+176+96+0+1+false+1+2%0AS+144+320+176+320+0+1+false+1+2%0Aw+144+128+176+128+0%0Aw+144+192+176+192+0%0Aw+144+288+144+320+0%0Aw+144+288+176+288+0%0Ap+176+192+176+288+1+0%0Ap+176+128+176+192+1+0%0Aw+144+128+144+96+0%0Ag+272+304+272+320+0%0Aw+272+192+288+192+2%0A403+304+112+432+176+0+1_64_0_4354_10_0.00009765625_0_2_1_3%0A403+304+224+432+288+0+9_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_9_3%0A403+432+176+544+240+0+2_64_0_4362_10_0.1_0_2_2_3%0Ax+301+40+427+43+4+12+click%5Csany%5Csganged%5Csswitch%0Aw+560+96+352+96+0%0Aw+368+304+560+304+0%0A38+1+0+0.000001+0.000101+Capacitance%0A38+2+0+0.01+1.01+Inductance%0A):
but 1C+4C using C=10uF and 4C=40uF as example results in even voltage ratios of 1/5+4/5 of 10V to get 8Vpp and 2Vpp swing on  each cap.

Since smaller cap 10uF example starts at 1Vp for positive peak 8V negative swing results in +1Vp,-7Vp.
While the bigger cap 40uF =4C starts at 4V with 1/(1+4)x10V = 2V and the balance 8V on the other starting from +1V to -7V.

Comment: Can you explain how the voltage drop to 5vo initially.

Comment: Vo+4Vo=5Vo .... precharged

Comment: You add the two capacitors and add their  voltages

Comment: Stewart sunnyskyguy sorry, but can please update your answer, because it is difficult for a high school boys please sir.

Comment: Thanks sir I got the answer

Comment: Don’t forget to vote and accept